# UMP test for one-sided hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, self-study, inference

Is it possible to identify a UMP test for one-sided hypotheses on $ \theta $  for
the case of an i.i.d. sample $ (X_1, ..., X_n) $ of random variables $ X_i \sim f_\theta (.) $ such that the parameter $ \theta $ appears in the support of $ f_\theta (.) $ ?

Is this referring to Karlin-Rubin Theorem?

I am a bit confused because of the parameter appearing in the support.

Thanks.